# Dynamically allocating an array of structs in Main and then having a function assign to it

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, calloc

I'm building a server for a project and I need to store a bunch of values in a ordered way. I've been searching for hours and I haven't figured out how.

I built a struct as follows:

```
struct WHITEBOARD{
    int line;
    char type;
    int bytes;
    char string[1024];  
} *Server;
```

Then in my main function I want to dynamically allocate memory to create an array of structs WHITEBOARD to a size of [argv[1]] (eventually). I would like to use calloc and in my research I have found the following:

```
void main()
{
    struct whiteboard (*Server) = (struct whiteboard*) calloc(10, sizeof(*Server));
    (*Server).line = 2;
    printf("Test: %d\n",(*Server).line);
}
```

This works but I can't seem to find out how to turn Server into an array of structs so that I can reference `(*Server)[1].line` and assign to this heap bound variable from a function. Which I intend to do as follows.

```
char* doThing(struct whiteboard Server)
{
    (*Server)[1].line = 4;
    return;
}
```

And be able to printf the newly bound variable from main.

This might be a dumb question, but any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: This code does not even compile....

Comment: `(*Server)[1].line` --> `Server[1].line`...what else?

Comment: Sorry, the structure and main() should compile together. The function however makes no sense. It's kind of a pseudocode for what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct WHITEBOARD{
    int line;
    char type;
    int bytes;
    char string[1024];  
} *Server;
```

You have a variable (a pointer to `struct WHITEBOARD`) called `Server` at global scope, thus, you don't need to redeclare-it inside `main` nor inside your function parameters, also note that you are misusing the dereference operator (`*`), to access the element `1` in `(*Server)[1].line = 4;` just use `Server[1].line = 4;`

```
void doThing(void) /* Changed, you promise to return a pointer to char but you return nothing */
{
    Server[1].line = 4;
}

int main(void) /* void main is not a valid signature */
{
    Server = calloc(10, sizeof(*Server)); /* Don't cast calloc */

    Server[1].line = 2;
    doThing();
    printf("Test: %d\n", Server[1].line);
    free(Server);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply get rid of all the obscure syntax you have invented, don't "guess the syntax" when you are not sure of how to do something.

- Keep struct declaration and variable declarations separate.
- Don't use global variables.
- Don't use parenthesis when there is no obvious need for it.
- Don't dereference a pointer with both `*` and `[]` operators in the same expression.
- Don't cast the result of calloc.
- Don't write functions that return a type and then return nothing.
- The signature of main() on a hosted system is `int main (void)`.
- Always free() allocated memory.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
  int line;
  char type;
  int bytes;
  char string[1024];  
} whiteboard_t;


void do_thing (whiteboard_t* server)
{
  server[1].line = 4;
}

int main (void) 
{
  int n = 10;
  whiteboard_t* server = calloc(n, sizeof(whiteboard_t));

  server[0].line = 2;
  printf("Test: %d\n",server[0].line);

  do_thing(server);
  printf("Test: %d\n",server[1].line);

  free(server);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `_t` type suffix is reserved by POSIX and it seems that OP wants an array of `10` elements, not an array of 10 * 10 elements, use `calloc(n, sizeof(whiteboard_t));` instead of `calloc(n, sizeof(whiteboard_t[n]));`

Comment: @KeineLust The question is about C not POSIX. That POSIX bans `_t` postfix is simply a design flaw in the POSIX standard, which I couldn't care less about. The C standard actively encourages the use of `_t` for typedefs. File a defect report to POSIX if you care. The typo has been fixed, thanks.